# Is it possible to access field outside of _source in elasticsearch Ingest Pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am having problems creating an ingest-pipe in elasticstack that has access to fields outside of `_source` object.  I am using elasticstack 7.8.  Here is a trivial example:

```json
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "processors": [
      {
         "set": {
            "field": "foo_found",
            "value": "true",
            "if": "ctx.foo != null && ctx.foo =~ /foo/"
         }
      },
      {
         "set": {
            "field": "bar_found",
            "value": "true",
            "if": "bar != null && bar =~ /bar/"
         }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "foo": "foofoo"
      },
      "bar":"barbar"
    }
  ]
}
```

The desired result is below:

```json
{
 "docs": [
   {
     "doc": {
      "_source": {
        "foo_found": "true",
        "foo": "foofoo",
        "bar_found": "true"
      },
      "bar":"barbar"
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

The pipeline fails to run.

Is it possible to access the `bar` field which is outside of `_source` object?

The example will run if the second `set` processor is removed as in the following:

```json
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "processors": [
      {
         "set": {
            "field": "foo_found",
            "value": "true",
            "if": "ctx.foo != null && ctx.foo =~ /foo/"
         }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_source": {
        "foo": "foofoo"
      },
      "bar":"barbar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense whatsoever to have fields outside of `_source`, which represents your document, except the "official" ones, i.e. `_id`, `_routing`and `_index`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/simulate-pipeline-api.html), to simulate an ingest pipeline we can only pass `_id`, `_index`, `_routing` and/or `_source` to the sample documents.